# python my date conversion function is throwing error while converting the datetime.date format to "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a list of dates in the following format:

```
# List of dates
List_of_Dates = [datetime.date(2019, 6, 3), datetime.date(2019, 6, 4), datetime.date(2019, 6, 5), datetime.date(2019, 6, 6), datetime.date(2019, 6, 7), datetime.date(2019, 6, 10), datetime.date(2019, 6, 11), datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)]
```

And then I defined a function for date conversion:

```
# define a function for date conversion
def Date_Converter(Date):
    import datetime
    Date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return(Date2)
```

But when I passed the above list of dates to the above function, in the following way:

```
# return the list of converted dates
Date_Converter(List_of_Dates)
```

I also tried:

```
[Date_Converter(x) for x in List_of_Dates]
```

But in both the cases, I got an error:

```
 ----> 5     Date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
  6     return(Date2)

 TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list
```

Whereas I was expecting the following list:

```
["2019-06-03", "2019-06-04", "2019-06-05", "2019-06-06", "2019-06-07", "2019-06-10", "2019-06-11", "2019-06-12"]
```

Comment: You pass in a `List_of_Dates` to your function. But the function expects a `Date`. I assume you miss a loop.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg - I assume a Lambda function can be build, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lambda function, you can do like this :

```py
date_Converter = lambda date: [str(date[i]) for i in range(len(date))]
```

which will return :

```
date_Converter(List_of_Dates)

['2019-06-03',
 '2019-06-04',
 '2019-06-05',
 '2019-06-06',
 '2019-06-07',
 '2019-06-10',
 '2019-06-11',
 '2019-06-12']
```

Comment: This is one liner shot in bull's eye. Thanks. but i ran with one different issue in here. `2019-06-03 00:00:00` I am getting hh:mm:ss also (although all zeros), but i do not want it at all. only "yyyy-mm-dd" is needed and not "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Found it... i should have used datetime.date() instead datetime.datetime()

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with your code, let's tackle them one by one.

**imports**

either `import datetime` or `from datetime import date` within one module. Pick one and stick to it, otherwise it will cause confusion.

**Creating a new date**

`datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)` is wrong, use `datetime(2019, 6, 3)` instead.

**Update:** I was under the assumption that you are useing datetime.datetime.date(), which cannot work, but datetime.date.date() works. Again, using meaningful imports can prevent this.

**Trying to *parse* a datetime object**

Instead of `strptime` (used to parse strings *into* datetime) you want to use `strftime` (to convert from datetime to string).

**Having a function that expects a single variable and passing it a list of variables**

Cannot work obviously. Unless you write the function in such a way that it can handle both single variables and lists.

---

Here's the fixed code:

```
from datetime import date

List_of_Dates = [date(2019, 6, 3), date(2019, 6, 4), date(2019, 6, 5)]

def Date_Converter(Date):
    return date.strftime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d")

new_list = [Date_Converter(d) for d in List_of_Dates]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not help here in the changing format, as this list comes from some another module's result as a list of dates in this format only.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that you're working with ``datetime.date``, while I assumed ``datetime.datetime.date``, see updated answer and "Update" note.

Answer (score 1):

Use **strftime** instead of **strptime**

```
    import datetime
lis = []
List_of_Dates = [datetime.date(2019, 6, 3), datetime.date(2019, 6, 4), 
                datetime.date(2019, 6, 5), datetime.date(2019, 6, 6), 
                datetime.date(2019, 6, 7), datetime.date(2019, 6, 10), 
                datetime.date(2019, 6, 11), datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)]
for i in List_of_Dates:
    date1 = datetime.datetime.strftime(i,'%Y-%m-%d')
    lis.append(date1)
print lis
```

**Output--**

```
['2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-06', '2019-06-07', '2019-06-10', '2019-06-11', '2019-06-12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the code corrected:

```
def Date_Converter(Date):
return  dt.datetime.strptime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()

output = [Date_Converter(List_of_Dates[a]) for a in 
range(len(List_of_Dates))]
```

and the output is a list of dates:

```
['2019-06-03',
 '2019-06-04',
 '2019-06-05',
 '2019-06-06',
 '2019-06-07',
 '2019-06-10',
 '2019-06-11',
 '2019-06-12']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a list to the function, and it expects a Date.

You can solve it this way I think:

```
import Datetime

result = []

for date in List_of_Dates:
    result.append(Date_Converter(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pythonic way is to use the popular `map`. like this: that will pass the list into the function.

```
import datetime 
# List of dates
List_of_Dates = [datetime.date(2019, 6, 3), datetime.date(2019, 6, 4), datetime.date(2019, 6, 5), datetime.date(2019, 6, 6), datetime.date(2019, 6, 7), datetime.date(2019, 6, 10), datetime.date(2019, 6, 11), datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)]
# define a function for date conversion
def Date_Converter(Date):    
    Date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Date),"%Y-%m-%d")
    return(str(Date2.date()))



map(Date_Converter,List_of_Dates)
```

result:

```
    ['2019-06-03',
 '2019-06-04',
 '2019-06-05',
 '2019-06-06',
 '2019-06-07',
 '2019-06-10',
 '2019-06-11',
 '2019-06-12']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# return the list of converted dates
Date_Converter(List_of_Dates)
```

This does nothing with the return value. Also, your names pretty much sum your problem - you pass a list, rather than a single date.

Fix for this line would be:

```
list_of_converted_dates = [Date_Converter(date) for date in List_of_Dates]
```

This collects a result for each date from your list.

However, you will encounter another problem after this: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime`

This error stems from how you try to convert your date - you do it the other way around: `datetime.datetime.strptime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()` tries to get a date from a string

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful suggestions and I will take care of these.